# Using LINQ to remove items from a list that do not apear in another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
//basic item class
public class myItem
{
   public Int Id { get; set;}
   public String Name { get; set;}
}

//My original List
List<myItem> masterList = new List<myItem>() { new myItem{id = 1, Name = "item 1"},
                                           new myItem{id = 2, Name = "item 2"},
                                           new myItem{id = 3, Name = "item 3"},
                                           new myItem{id = 4, Name = "item 4"}
                                          };

//List of ids of items I want to KEEP in my original list
List<int> keepList = new List<int>() {2,3};
```

Basically I want to remove all items that arent id 2 or 3 from my master list

Comment: LINQ is used to query data, I don't think it's actually possible to modify the underlying collection. What you can do is have a `.Where` clause and create a new collection with it that suits your criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class myItem
{
   public int id { get; set;}
   public String Name { get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    //My original List
    List<myItem> masterList = new List<myItem>() { new myItem{ id = 1, Name = "item 1"},
                                            new myItem{id = 2, Name = "item 2"},
                                            new myItem{id = 3, Name = "item 3"},
                                            new myItem{id = 4, Name = "item 4"}
                                            };

    //List of ids of items I want to KEEP in my original list
    List<int> keepList = new List<int>() {2,3}; 

    // what you want
    masterList = masterList.Where(i => keepList.Contains(i.id)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre. Would this be okay?

masterList = masterList.Where(i => keepList.Contains(i.id)).ToList();

Comment: Yes.. that would be ok.

Comment: @Ghandicap, if you think my answer helped you, please feel free to mark as an answer, thank you.